# Emotion detection on audio

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn, audio-recognition, ai

I'm trying to apply emotion detection on audio. Basically, given an audio file, it must generate emotional labels for a segment of any durations, say every 5s chunks, like happy, sad, angry, etc.

Is there a working example with pretrained models available to test? I was looking for a sample on GitHub, but had problems running it. I need a relatively accurate model. Any working sample would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here is the [github](https://github.com/alexmuhr/Voice_Emotion) and here is the [explanantion](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-vocal-emotion-sensor-with-deep-learning-bedd3de8a4a9).

Comment: Thanks. It was exactly the one I couldn't find out how to run. It has a pretrained model. Can you share the piece of code that can do prediction given an audio file?